# Download Large PDF Files (Bigger Than 150 MB) With Crystal Report

Tags: oracle, google-chrome, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, bigdata

I have .net mvc project.  This web project has a screen which can download report file with specified credentials. This screen use  Crystal Report. User specifies inputs and then click the download button after that stored procedure is executed to fetch data. User can download pdf files which's size is any kbytes. But sometimes stored procedure fetch big data with some inputs. Pdf size is greater then 125 MB such cases. I debug all the code. When flow come EXportToDisk method and after that chrome give 'Transaction aborted' error.

How can i download pdf which size's 150-160 MB with Crystal Report in Google Chrome. What can i do to download big pdf files with Crystal Report. How can i block Google Chrome 'Transaction Aborted' error.